# How to reset jsDOM functions which has been overwritten

Tags: node.js, jestjs, jsdom

I am overwriting jsdom localstorage API like this in jest, so as to test my try catch code.

```
    Storage.prototype.setItem = jest.fn(() => {
        throw new Error("error");
    });
```

How do  reset its implementation ?

I am presently doing this. Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

```
    const setImplementation = Storage.prototype.setItem;
    Storage.prototype.setItem = jest.fn(() => {
        throw new Error("error");
    });
    expect(() => {
        localStorageHelper.setData(key, value);
    }).not.toThrow();
    Storage.prototype.setItem = setImplementation;
    done();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object methods should never be mocked by assigning, exactly because they cannot be restored this way. Restoring them manually is reinventing the wheel because this can be handled by Jest:

```
jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem').mockImplementation(() => {
    throw new Error("error");
});
```

A mock like this one should be used with `jest.restoreAllMocks()` or `restoreMock` configuration option to be consistently restored without a risk to affect other tests.

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to fix my test case.